# Measurable functions are almost locally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

This is a question from Terrence Tao's textbook "Introduction to Measure Theory"
Let f : $\mathbb{R}$ → $\mathbb{C}$ be a measurable function supported on a set of finite measure, and let ε > 0. Show that there exists a measurable set
E ⊂ $\mathbb{R}^d$ of measure at most ε outside of which f is locally bounded, or in other words that for every R > 0 there exists
M < ∞ such that |f(x)| ≤ M for all x ∈ B(0,R)\E.

I'm not quite sure where to start here. In the text description, it says that this is a "littlewood-like" principle but not sure of the relation. Could I get a hint towards this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by finding a set $ E_1 $ of measure less than $ \varepsilon / 2 $ outside of which $ f $ is bounded on $ B(0,1)\backslash E_1 $.  Then find a set $ E_2 $ of measure less than $ \varepsilon / 4 $ outside of which $ f $ is bounded on $ B(0,2)\backslash E_2 $.  Keep going, and define $ E_1, E_2, E_3, \ldots $.  Does this hint help?  Do you see how you can proceed from here?

Comment: So then when I take the union of all the sets it is has a measure that is equal to the summation of an infinite series equal to . If I show that do I need to show  for every R > 0 there exists M < ∞ such that |f(x)| ≤ M for all x ∈ B(0,R)\E?

Comment: I claim that the existence of such an $ M $ is clear from the construction I outlined.  I encourage you to write those details yourself.